# How to refresh previous fragment after closing an activity?

Tags: android, fragment, refresh, back, recreate

I have a fragment that throws an activity in which user can insert some details.
When the user terminate to fill data the activity close. Then the previous fragment is showed and I want it to be updated (with the data provided by user in the activity).

If it was an activity, instead of fragment, i could use this:

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    recreate();
}
```

How to do the same with fragment?

Answer (score 1):

You would override onResume in the Activity which this Fragment belong, and recreate (restarted) this Fragment in this Activity. For example

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        //  here you can get the Fragment  instance , so you can recreated this fragment      here or invoke this fragment's function to set data or refresh data
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can throw an Activity in  calling startActivityForResult (Intent intent, int requestCode) method in your fragment.

also you need to provide onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) in your fragment,the data is in the Intent parameter.

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment {

     public void throwActivity() {
            // start activity
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(getActivity(), YourActivity.class);
            int requestCode = 1;
            startActivityForResult(intent,requestCode);
        }

        // callback
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

            recreate();

        }

        public void recreate() {
            // your refresh code
        }
}
public class YourActivity extends Activity {

    public void yourMethod() {

           int resultCode = 2;
           setResult(resultCode);    // goback to your fragment with your data
        }
}
```

Comment: I do not need to pass data from activity to fragment. I need that when i came back to fragment it has to be recreated (restarted).

Comment: Sorry, i have updated my question because i was wrong.

Comment: Can you edit your code in a way that no data is needed to be passed from activity to fragment? In addition there are some errors: line 3 (missing parenthesis), line 6 (use getActivity() instead of this)

Comment: Sorry,I typed code in plain text editor,and I have updated the code above.

Comment: What to write in recreate method?
Have i to use yourMethod() before finish()?

Comment: Maybe I have misunderstood your question or you did not express your question clearly.

Comment: Because I think you want to refresh your fragment when back from your activity.

Comment: I asked this because i do not know what to write for refreshing

Comment: Okay,I misunderstood it.